# Combining two circulating normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution

I am working in estimating the impact of location error on location based services. My question is listed below.
If the error distribution of location estimation follows in general a normal distribution $N_1(0,\sigma_1)$. However, after a time interval $t_1$, the error follows another distribution $N_2(0,\sigma_2)$ for a time interval $t_2$. Then, it returns back to distribution $N_1$ for $t_1$, and so on. My question is how to combine both distributions to represent the final distribution of the location error? Everything is independent i.e. $N_1$ and $N_2$ is independent and $t_1$ and $t_2$ is independent as

Comment: is the final distribution = $t_1/(t_1+t_2)*N_1 + t_2/(t_1+t_2)*N_2$?